# Different ways of using a variable across different subroutines

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set up a sub to be called upon and use the value of its result in the main sub.  So far I've been using Function to carry over the value.  However, I was wondering if there are any alternative ways of doing the same thing?  I figured ByVal/ByRef is another way to do it by using a Sub instead of Function.  My current codes are as follow:

```
Sub Main()
Dim i as Long

i = lr("A")

'some other calculations using i
End Sub

Function lr(Tar As String) As Long
Dim twb As Workbook
Set twb = ThisWorkbook

lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Tar & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

My question is, How would I write this if I were to use a Sub instead of Function?  Thanks!

Comment: Add you mentioned, you can use ByRef, or you could also use a global variable. Neither of those are preferable to a function.

Comment: I agree with Tim. What you have is the best way to handle it :)

Comment: Why do you want to use a sub instead of a function?  Will it generate side effects?

Comment: @Degustaf I was uncomfortable about the fact that function has to return "something", but now that I think about it, like the answer below pointed out, I think I was concerned with wanting to return more than just a single value from a procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *So far I've been using Function to carry over the value.*

Great, that's what functions are for! When you only need to return a single value, the best way is always going to be a function.

Things get fuzzier when you start needing to return two or more values. You could:

- Use `ByRef` parameters and use them as "out" values.

  This is "ok" for *procedures* (`Sub`), and confusing for functions - what determines which parameter gets to be the function's return value, and which parameters get to be passed `ByRef`? How does the calling code know whether or not to pass an initialized value to those `ByRef` parameters?

  A naming convention can help here:

  ```
  Public Sub Foo(ByVal foo1 As String, ByRef outBar1 As String, ByRef outBar2 As String)
  ```

  An "out" prefix can tell the calling code that the parameter is an *out* value.
- Scope the variables at a level that is accessible by both the caller and the callee.

  This is a bad practice that can easily lead to spaghetti code. Avoid it - variables should have the smallest necessary scope possible, and be *passed* between methods/functions/procedures/modules, not just globally scoped and accessed by anyone at any given time!
- Create a class to encapsulate all the values the function should return.

  Definitely more *object-oriented*, results in much cleaner, readable code. The only downside is that VBA doesn't really encourage you to do this, and *consistently* doing that will result in a myriad of classes that you can't quite organize.

Comment: + 1 nicely explained :)

Comment: ++ for using Hungarian notation ***the right way***

Comment: @RubberDuck really... ++ for the notation? Lol ;)

Comment: @vba4all yes. It gives me a reason to reference [JoelOnSoftware](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). =;)-